# How do you find the probability of a brownian motion?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

If $B(t)$ is a brownian motion what do these two questions mean?
1. What is the probability of $B(2)$
2. What is the probability of $B(2) \gt B(1)$

I know this is also called a Wiener Process and I think a brownian motion has a normal distribution with mean $0$ and variance $t$, but I don't understand what the probability of $B(t)$ means?

Comment: It likely means "what is the distribution of $B(2)$?", in which case your answer is correct.

Comment: It could also be a typo, as in they meant to write $B(2)>B(1)$, or something like that. But as it stands, the best interpretation seems to be "the distribution".

Comment: I changed it, I made the questions up because i'm not sure how to find the probability of a brownian motion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It should be distribution of $B(2)$ most likely, and thus is $N(0,2)$.
2. $1/2$, since this is $P(B(2)-B(1)>0)$ and $B(2)-B(1)$ is a normal distribution with zero mean and is thus >0 with probability $1/2$

Comment: Would the probability that B(3) > B(2) > B(1) be 1/2, also?

Comment: user151876: Probability that $B(3) > B(2) > B(1)$ is $P(B_3-B_2>0, B_2-B_1>0)$. Since the two probabilities are independent, we can product them since $B_3-B_2$ and $B_2-B_1$ are independent. Thus, we should get $1/4$ and not $1/2$.